# IntPtr is not properly marshaled in mono

Tags: c#, c++, mono, marshalling, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to do a function P/Invoke using Mono on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
[DllImport(@"libRT", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern uint DoChallenge(
        IntPtr pEncryptedBlob,
        uint dwEncryptedBlobLen,
        IntPtr pDecryptedBlob,
        uint dwMaxLen,
        ref uint dwDecryptedBlobLen);
```

Before I invoke the function in C#, I print the encrypted and decrypted values:

```
Console.WriteLine(pEncryptedBlob.ToString()); // value is 140640247632608
Console.WriteLine(pDecryptedBlob.ToString()); // values is 140640247634240

// Do the challenge
this.errorCode = DoRtasChallenge(pEncryptedBlob, pDecryptedBlob,
                    (uint)this.decryptedBlobBuffer.Length,
                    ref this.decryptedBlobReturnLength);
```

Now in C++ code I print the values that I receive:

```
APIFUNC uint32_t DoChallenge(unsigned char * pEncryptedBlob,long dwEncryptedBlobLen,unsigned char * pDecryptedBlob,long dwMaxLen,long * dwDecryptedBlobLen)
{ 
    fprintf(stderr, "pEncryptedBlob: %ld \n",pEncryptedBlob);
    fprintf(stderr, "pDecryptedBlob: %ld \n",pDecryptedBlob);

    // the output: 
    // pEncryptedBlob: 1 
    // pDecryptedBlob: 140640603072256 
}
```

So  it looks like both of IntPtrs are getting modified during the marshaling.

I assume that this happens specifically because of Mono/Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit environment, because it works on Windows and Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit.

Any ideas for the workaround? Thanks very much

Comment: #define APIFUNC extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

Comment: I don't know a lot about marshalling, but I bet that the `sizeof(long)` is 8. It is on my 64-bit Ubuntu system under gcc. Use `int` or one of the sized types from `<cstdint>`. Or make two versions of the function in C# and call the proper one.

Comment: just found a workaround :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove platform specific implementation so your C# & c/cpp code will run xplat  you should just pass a C# "System.String" to "const char *src". Interop marshalling will handle the rest.

C signature of:

```
void myfunc (const char *src, size_t n);
```

C# DllImport of:

```
private static extern void myCfunc (string src, uint n);
```

Usage:

```
var myString = "Test";
myCfunc(myString, myString.Length);
```

Interop with Native Libraries :
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Answer (score -1):

I just found a workaround, I am forcing my IntPtrs to be marshaled as 4 bytes:

```
[DllImport(@"libRT", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern uint DoChallenge(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] // this is a fix
    IntPtr pEncryptedBlob,
    uint dwEncryptedBlobLen,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    IntPtr pDecryptedBlob,
    uint dwMaxLen,
    ref uint dwDecryptedBlobLen);
```

Result:

C# result:

```
139700723537696
139700723538064
```

C++ result:

```
pEncryptedBlob: 139700723537696 
pDecryptedBlob: 139700723538064
```